# c#/.NET - selecting rows from a datatable using DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, select, datatable, datatables

I'm trying to select rows from a datatable where the DateTime in one of the columns is between a start date and an end date, for example: `date > '2017-09-04 00:00:00' AND <= date '2017-09-04 23:59:59'`.

The Select is returning nothing even though I know that the rows between the two DateTime's exist.

**My code:**

```
string selectExp = "Date > '" + eDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00") + "' AND Date <= '" + eDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd 23:59:59") + "'";

DataRow[] drForCurDate = eDataTable.Select(selectExp);
```

My select expression string:

```
"Date > '2017-08-14 00:00:00' AND Date <= '2017-08-14 23:59:59'"
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to fix it to get the results that I need?
Any help appreciated!

Comment: Tip:Date fields does not contain strings..Look the sample code [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/det4aw50(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It works for me, [see this LINQPad script](http://share.linqpad.net/64f99h.linq). Are you absolutely sure your data table has dates that satisfy the filter?

Comment: 100% sure. So frustrating :(

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that maybe you don't actually have a column named `Date`.

Answer (score 1):

And what about something like

```
db.where(x=>x.someDate > minDate && x.someDate < maxDate)
```